# I am new to OpenJ9 and require profiling tools for OpenJ9 in RCP application

Tags: openj9

i just didn’t find any tools on how to measure the performance imporvement compared to Hotspot JVM.
PLease share me the details on where i can find the profiling tools. For example profiling tools like JvisualVM

Comment: You might be interested in JProfiler and Dynatrace. I have found Dynatrace very effective to trace generic applications.

Comment: is there any license free profiling tool for OpenJ9 ?